# Why is $(1+1)(1+1)=1+1+1+1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Why is $(1+1)(1+1)=1+1+1+1$?

What I found really strange is that when one defines $a:=1+1$, we would have$$a\cdot a=a+a$$ which is obviously false for any $a\in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: "$[\ldots]$ *when one defines* $a:=1+1$, *we would have* $a\cdot a=a+a$ *which is obviously false for any* $a\in \mathbb{N}$" --- Try $a=2.$

Comment: It's obviously false as a statement about *all* $a \in \mathbb{N}$; but it's not false for *this particular* $a$.

Comment: What do you mean it is false for any $a\in \mathbb N$.  It's obviously true for $a = 2$.  It's not true for any *other* $a \ne 2$ but no other $n$ is equal to $1+1$.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean "for any", but "for all".

Comment: $a^2=2a$ has two solutions: $a=2$ and $a=0$.

Comment: You find $a^2 -2a = (a-2)a=0 if and only if $a=0,2$

Comment: Well, it's *not* true for all.  It's only true for $a=1+1$.  In any field there is *only* one $a=1+1$.  And for *that* $a$ we have $a^2 = a + a$ but we don't have it for any *other*. (except $0$).

Comment: But $0\notin \mathbb{N}$

Comment: But don't you think it's odd? Is it not always possible to substitute?

Comment: You comment is a bit like saying:  It is very strange that $3+4 = 7$ because that means $a + b = 7$ and that's obviously not true for all $a$ and $b$.

Comment: "But don't you think it's odd?"  Honestly?  No, not in the least bit.   "Is it not always possible to substitute? " Substitue what.  Every field  will have an element equal to $a= 1_F + 1_F$.  This element and this element *only* will be such that $a^2 = a+a; a\ne 0$.  That every field where $1+1 \ne 0$ will have such an element with that property is not at all odd.  Consider it a Theorem: For any field where $1_F + 1_F\ne 0$ there will be exactly one non-zero element $a$ where $a^2 = a+a$ and $a$ will be the element $1_F + 1_F$.  ... As a theorem it is a sensible one.

Comment: Do you accept that $2 = 1+1$ and if $a \ne 2$ then $a \ne 1+1$?  So if you have $a =1 + 1$ then $a=2$ is the only possible natural number where $a = 1+1$.  Do you find *that* odd?

Comment: But you’re not “substituting.” You’re doing pretty much the opposite of that: you’re trying to generalize from only one example. There are some disciplines in which that might be acceptable, but it pretty much never works in mathematics.

Comment: Okay.... we don't always have $a^2 = a+ a$ but we *do* always have $a^2 = (a+a) + a([a-1] - 1)$  (expand it out).  And if $a= 1+1$ we have $a([a -1] -1 ) = 0$.

Comment: " There are some disciplines in which ;generalizing from one example' acceptable"  Is that a dig?  I'd say that that is not acceptable in any discipline.

Answer (score 6):

Because\begin{align}(1+1)(1+1)&=1\times(1+1)+1\times(1+1)\\&=(1+1)+(1+1).\end{align}

Comment: Why is that true? Wouldn't this mean $a\times b=1\cdot a+1\cdot b$

Comment: What is $a$ and what is $b$?

Comment: It's distribution.  $(a+b)(c+d) = a(c+d) + b(c+d) = ac + ad + bc +bd$.  If $b = 1+c$ we'd have $ab=a(1+c)= 1\cdot a + ac$ and if $c = 1$ and $b=a$ we'd have $ab = 1\cdot a + 1\cdot b$.  But you wouldn't have it *always*.  Just sometimes.  There's nothing weird about *SOME* numbers having a special property.  It's only weird if *ALL* do.  And they don't.  $1 + 1$ is a special and unique number.

Comment: @ParabolicAlcoholic Draw it out with dots on a paper

Answer (score 6):

I think you are confusing equations that are true *all the time* (these are usually called identities) and equations that are true *some of the time* (you are often asked to find those times).

In the real numbers (and, in general, in rings) the distributive law is true all the time:
$$
a \times (c + d) = a \times c + a \times d .
$$
You can use the distributive law three times to show that for all $a,b,c,d$
$$
(a + b) \times (c + d) = a \times c + a \times d +  b \times c + b \times d .
$$
When in particular you happen to have $a=b=c=d=1$ you get the number $4$ two different ways, which surprises you. But there is nothing you can derive from the rules for arithmetic that says that this identity will always be true:
$$
a \times a = a + a .
$$
With that equation you want to ask about what values of $a$ make it true. It's not hard to show that only $2$ and $0$ work.

Comment: @fleablood Thanks. You could have fixed it.

Comment: Oh... Yeah, I don't like editing other people's posts if there is any possibility I am changing what the meant to say.

Answer (score 3):

$2 + 2 = 2*2$.

This will hold for any field if we define $2:= 1+1$.

There is nothing odd about this, as $(1+1)(1+1) = 1(1+1) + 1(1+1) = (1+1)+(1+1)$.

It will not hold for any *OTHER* value *except* for $2:=1+1$. (Well, It's true of $0$ but...)

But in general $a*a = a^2$ and $a + a = 2a$.  For $a^2 = 2a$ and $a \ne 0$ we will have $a^2*a^{-1} = 2*a*a^{-1}$ and $a = 2$.

That's the *only* non-zero solution but it is not a surprising one.

=====

Maybe consider this.

For any $a$ in any field,  we have $a^2 = a + a(a-1) = a + a + a([a-1]-1) = (a+a) + a([a-1]-1)$.

So we always have $a^2 = a + a + SOMETHING$ where $SOMETHING = a([a-1] -1)$.

If $a$ happens to be the element $1+1$ we have:

$SOMETHING = a([(1+1)-1]-1) = a([1]-1) = a\cdot 0 = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

The equation $$ a\times a = a+a$$ is not false for all natural numbers.

It has the obvious solution of $$a=2$$ because $$2\times 2=2+2=4$$
It also has the solution $a=0$ which is not a natural number.

Comment: $0$ can be a natural number; it depends on your construction of the set of natural numbers.

Comment: In a field.  If you define $2$ as $1+1$ then $a^2 = a+a$ will have exactly two solutions.  $0$ and $2:=1+1$ will be the only non-zero solution.

Comment: Yes you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Check the left side: $(1+1)(1+4) = 4$.

Now, check the right side: $1+1+1+1 = 4$.

Since the LHS=RHS, equality holds.

Answer (score 0):

> Lets define an [algebraic structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_structure) where your identity works for a given indeterminate $a$.

Take the set $\{a\}$ and consider the free (two sided) $\mathbb{Z}$ [module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_module) over it. Now lets define a multiplication on this module declaring $a^2=2a.$ Then for any two elements $\alpha a, \beta a\in\mathbb{Z}[a]$ of the module, we can have $$(\alpha a)(\beta a)=2(\alpha\beta) a$$ and $$a^n=2^na$$ for any $n\in\mathbb{N}.$